# php,mysql, update users details form

Tags: php, mysql, session

I want to update a users information if he wishes to such as his first name, password and avatar picture. I don't know how and where to keep the UPDATE sql statement. These changes would be made in the profile page

profile.php:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}


<form action="profile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
<fieldset>
    <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Your firstname" required>
    <label for="password">Password:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Your new password">
    <label>Upload a new profile picture: </label><input type="file" name="avatar" accept="image/*" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Changes" name="changes"  />                        
</fieldset>
```

users.php

```
    <?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    //two passwords are equal to each other
    if ($_POST['password'] == $_POST['confirmpassword']) {

        //define other variables with submitted values from $_POST
        $firstName = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['firstName']);
        $lastName = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['lastName']);
        $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $date = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['regDate']);

        //we can also do md5 hash password for security
        //  $password = md5($_POST['password']);
        //  
        //path were our avatar image will be stored
        $avatar_path = $mysqli->real_escape_string('images/' . $_FILES['avatar']['name']);

        //checking email

        //make sure the file type is image, image properties validates
        if (preg_match("!image!", $_FILES['avatar']['type'])) {

            //copy image to images/ folder 
            if (copy($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $avatar_path)) {
                //if email does not already exist
                //set session variables to display on the index page
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['avatar'] = $avatar_path;

                //insert user data into database
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (firstName, lastName, username, email, password, avatar, regDate) "
                        . "VALUES ('$firstName','$lastName','$username', '$email', '$password', '$avatar_path', NOW())";

                //check if mysql query is successful
                if ($mysqli->query($sql) === true) {
                    header("location: index.php");
                } else {
                    $_SESSION['message'] = 'User could not be added to the database!';
                }
                $mysqli->close();
            } else {
                $_SESSION['message'] = '';
            }
        } else {
            $_SESSION['message'] = '';
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = '';
    }
}
```

I also have a register.php where the following is code is there:
such as the session start;
and the connection and it requires from users

updateUser:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        //define other variables with submitted values from $_POST
        $firstName = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['firstName']);
        $password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

        $avatar_path = $mysqli->real_escape_string('images/' . $_FILES['avatar']['name']);

        //make sure the file type is image, image properties validates
        if (preg_match("!image!", $_FILES['avatar']['type'])) {

            //copy image to images/ folder 
            if (copy($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $avatar_path)) {
                //if email does not already exist
                //set session variables to display on the index page
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['avatar'] = $avatar_path;

                //insert user data into database
                $sql = "UPDATE INTO users (firstName, password, avatar) "
                        . "VALUES ('$firstName', '$password', '$avatar_path'";

                //check if mysql query is successful
                if ($mysqli->query($sql) === true) {
                    echo 'updated successfully';
                    header("location: index.php");
                } else {
                    $_SESSION['message'] = 'User could not be added to the database!';
                }
                $mysqli->close();
            } else {
                $_SESSION['message'] = 'File upload failed!';
            }
        } else {
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Please only upload GIF, JPG or PNG images!';
        }
    }
```

updated profile.php

```
    session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}
$text = "Welcome to your profile page";


$_SESSION['message'] = '';
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "");

require 'updateUser.php';
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I don't see an `UPDATE table..............`, *do you?*

Comment: I don't know where and how to keep it. I should create a new table in the database? no right?

Comment: why would you want to create a new table; why not just UPDATE it?

Comment: `//we can also do md5 hash password for security
        //  $password = md5($_POST['password']);` - I see you're not using that; good. It's totally "not" safe nor secure.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the new `UPDATE` query in another file if you'd like which would be the `action="newfilename.php"` and from there you can use `$_POST["firstname"]` and the other inputs to then add them to your SQL query.

Comment: Can you please show me how, I created an updateUser.php with only the 3 name, password and avatar  that I need.  It does not update the table and error is caused with the username displayed

Comment: Please can you show me the code so I can see how far you've gotten :)

Comment: Hi @dalmatian, did you manage to get this working? Sorry was busy. Let's figure this one out.